# create new database from c# and copying data from grid view in it

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I have a data grid view and data is stored in it after processing,I want to *create* a new table in database and *copy* the data from grid view to that table.

```
  command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE MyTable (" +
            "[Count] INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ," +
            "[TimeAndDate] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ," +
            "[SerialNumber] VARCHAR( 14 ) NOT NULL ," +
            "[Result] BOOL NOT NULL ," +
            "UNIQUE ([TimeAndDate]))";
```

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
this is for creating table but how to copy content from grid view,i don't know

Comment: It could very useful to add to your question what have you tried and what problems have you had

Comment: Winforms or wpf? Entity framework? add some details

Comment: Winforms,and i creating this database through c#

Answer (score 0):

After creating the table you just have to iterate through your datagridview rows and execute the insert statements